# How do I copy files outside my home directory?

Tags: paste

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Copy and paste outside my home directory is not working using the command line as well as through the menu option. While I am able to copy from the menu option, paste option is still gray.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In which directory are you trying to paste?

Comment: Other than the home directory.

Comment: Only inside your home directory you have write permission. To copy any file to a location (that is not owned by you) you need to have superuser privilege. Try `sudo cp -r </path/to/source> </path/to/destination>`

Comment: Can I change permissions to write down in other directories? If possible, how?

Comment: that would be really very very bad idea. it will disturb the natural functionality of Ubuntu and you might end up badly. It will be helpful if you tell us why do you want to copy in such a strange manner?

Comment: I want to keep some information form one computer to this one. So I am trying to copy them form my pen drive and to pest them in proper directories. So I like to get the pest option in my right click.

Comment: @Dutta I took the liberty and included the information that you want to copy files from outside your home folder.

Comment: @MadMike I am copying form a pen drive and trying to pest outside my home directory.

Comment: @Dutta when you restore system files you will also have to make sure that the owner the group and read/write permissions are set to the original state. Have a look at it the with `ls -al /path/to/the/file` and be sure that they are the same after you copy them. Please add the recovery scenario and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/538503/edit) your question so we can help better to solve your problem.

Comment: @MadMike Thank you for this commend ls-al. It gave me all the permission settings. I got which permissions was not enabled. Then by sudo I have made some correction. problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to recover files outside your home folder

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

Lets say you have a copied `/var/www/html/index.php` to your USB-drive and want to copy it back. Before we copy it back and erase the current file we need to have a look who is the current file owner, to which group belongs the file and what permissions it has.

```
madmike@computer:~$ ls -al /var/www/html/index.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 182 Jan 21  2014 /var/www/html/index.php
```

The `-rw-rw-r--` are the read, write and execution rights of the file. The very first character indicates if this a directory (those are marked with "d") or a file (marked with "-"). The next 3 characters are those for the owner. "rw-" means "read rights and writing rights, but no no execution right". The next 3 characters are those for the group and which are the same now. And then the last 3 character for all the other users "r--" meaning "only read rights". The file belongs to the user "www-data" on to the group "www-data".

To be on the save side, you might first want to move the original file away. You will need administrative rights to do this. That's why we will need to do it with `sudo`.

```
madmike@computer:~$ sudo mv /var/www/html/index.php /var/www/html/index.php.old
```

Now copy the file from the USB-drive.

```
madmike@computer:~$ sudo cp /media/madmike/usb-drive-name-here/backup-folder/index.php /var/www/html/index.php
```

Let's see what permissions this file now has:

```
madmike@computer:~$ ls -al /var/www/html/index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 182 Oct 18 13:17 /var/www/html/index.php
```

Now the owner and group is "root" and the group rights have changed from "rw-" to "r--". Let's fix this.

```
madmike@computer:~$ sudo chown www-data:www-data
madmike@computer:~$ ls -al /var/www/html/index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 182 Oct 18 13:19 /var/www/html/index.php
```

Ownership is fixed. Now the permissions.

```
madmike@computer:~$ sudo chmod ug=rw,o=r /var/www/html/index.php
madmike@computer:~$ ls -al /var/www/html/index.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 182 Oct 18 13:21 /var/www/html/index.php
```

Voilà. Everything is fixed. You may delete the copy now.

```
madmike@computer:~$ sudo rm /var/www/html/index.php.old
```

This [page](https://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/permissions.html) will show you some more examples on how you can use `chmod`. If you need an exhaustive list of all possibilities, then have a look at the man page. Issue this command in the terminal

```
madmike@computer:~$ man chmod
```